# IF: how to refer the multiplication of function outputs to the command TEST

Tags: bash, function, if-statement, numbers, sh

So I'm curling a json file and parsing it. The result is a number. Each one of these functions outputs a different number. I want the output in a Math equation, that's gonna go in IF statements.

```
function func() {
    curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com | jq -r '.[] | .[] | 
.interger'
}
function func2() {
    curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com | jq -r '.[] | .[] | 
.interger'
}
function func3() {
    curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com | jq -r '.[] | .[] | 
.interger'
}


if func*func2*func3 / func2*func3*func -ge 1
then
echo "yay"
fi
if func*func2*func3 / func2*func3*func -lt 1
then
echo "nay"
fi
```

Currently It is not doing any type of multiplication or division on the if statement, therefore making statement obsolete.

So far I've tried:

```
if [func*func2*func3 / func2*func3*func -ge 1]
then
echo "yay"
fi
if [func*func2*func3 / func2*func3*func -lt 1]
then
echo "nay"
fi
```

Comment: Not the same this is with functions not variables, so its not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic is done with `((...))`. Capturing output is done with `$(...)`.

```
if (($(func)*$(func2)*$(func3) / $(func2)*$(func3)*$(func) >= 1)); then
    echo "yay"
fi
```

Comment: ./blah.sh: line 28: 0.069290
0.069291
0.069266
0.069263 * 0.029013
0.029014
0.029003
0.028957 * 0.419282
0.419409
0.418156
0.417817 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".069290
0.069291
0.069266
0.069263 * 0.029013
0.029014
0.029003
0.028957 * 0.419282
0.419409
0.418156
0.417817 ")

Comment: thats the output with your script ^^

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Floating point arithmentic?, I'm sorry I"m kinda new

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [[ $(( $(func) * $(func2) * $(func3) )) -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo yay
else
  echo nay
fi
```

The `$(func)` calls substitute the value in the command; the `$(( ... ))` performs arithmetic evaluation.